# Not killing background processes when exiting an xming / xlaunch gnome-session

Tags: gnome, background-process

I am logging in to a remote linux box using `xlaunch` with `gnome-session --display=$DISPLAY`. If I start a background process, is there a way to have it stay alive (keep running) when I exit Xming so that it completes or still shows up when I log-in again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; when your X session goes away all programs using it lose their connection to the X server, which typically causes them to exit.  It is possible to arrange for programs that require neither X11 nor a terminal to be persistent, but if it needs either of those then it cannot survive loss of access to the Display.

If you want a persistent X session, take a look at VNC.  I've used [X11VNC](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc) for this but there are other ways to set up persistent sessions.

Comment: Yes, for persistent sessions you need a persistent *X* server. *Xvnc* is a great candidate.